# Run a Neo4j traversal JAR as an API

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, neo4j

I've coded a traversal in Java (using Eclipse IDE). The main() program accepts input arguments (classic args[]), it calls the traversal using one of them as the  start node, the other args are used to perform some data filtering on traversal results.
Thus, I can run this JAR on a command line with corresponding arguments.

Question: **how can quickly test this JAR as a RESTful API?** e.g. sending HTTP GET with its parameters as input arguments ? what is best practice ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create an [unmanaged extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) which will accept query parameters that will call your traversal

Example from the doc :

```
@Path( "/helloworld" )
public class HelloWorldResource
{
    private final GraphDatabaseService database;

    public HelloWorldResource( @Context GraphDatabaseService database )
    {
        this.database = database;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
    @Path( "/{nodeId}" )
    public Response hello( @PathParam( "nodeId" ) long nodeId )
    {
        // Do stuff with the database
        return Response.status( Status.OK ).entity(
                ("Hello World, nodeId=" + nodeId).getBytes( Charset.forName("UTF-8") ) ).build();
    }
}
```

You can find a **test** example here : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.2.1/community/server-examples/src/test/java/org/neo4j/examples/server/unmanaged/UnmanagedExtensionsDocIT.java

Comment: Thank you for the unmanaged extension definition, I didn't know.